# Find maximum scoring characters with non overlapping occurrences from a string

Tags: algorithms, strings

I have a problem related to Episode Mining in which I need to find the maximal utility of a episode given its occurrences in an event sequence.But I am presenting the question in a different form so that it's easier to explain.

There is a long string, *S*, where each of its character have some positive score. Given another string, *T*, find a match with *S* containing all occurrences of the sequence of characters of T such that :-

The occurrences are non-overlapping.
The sequence of characters in *S* must be same as present in *T* but it can be discontinous.
Each occurrence should lie in a given window.
The total score of a match can be found by simply adding the scores of the characters at each occurrence.The problem is to find a match with maximum score of all the matches possible.

**Example** - String *S* - a(2) b(3) e(1) d(10) d(7) c(1) a(5) d(8) b(5) d(6)

String *T* - a b d

Window size - 5

Two matches of string *T* are:-

[1,2,4], [7,9,10]. Score - [2+3+10] + [5+5+6]= 31
[1,2,5], [7,9,10]. Score - [2+3+7] + [5+5+6]= 28. And the score is maximum in match 1 so it is the required answer.
We didn't consider the occurrence [1,2,8] or [1,2,10] as they are not in the given window as (8-1) > 5.

So, I would like to know if there is some solution to find the set of occurences or match that gives the maximum score efficiently.